# Retrieve input values from dinamically genrated HTMLElement form?

Tags: html, json, angular, forms

I'm currently on an Angular project (I'm a begineer) and I created a function to create a HTML form depending on the content of a JSON (the form then allows me to push new data in the JSON). It works, displays the form, but I didn't think ahead, and don't know how to retrieve the input values from the user.

```js
 createNewLineForm() {
    if (this.allowForm) {
      let indiceList = 0;
      this.formOn = true;

      for (let jsonCol of this.columnData) {

        if (jsonCol.visible === true && jsonCol.type === "Boolean") {

          var content = document.getElementById("formcontent");

          var listTitle = document.createElement("header");
          listTitle.textContent = jsonCol.name;

          content.appendChild(listTitle);

          var selectList = document.createElement("select");
          selectList.id = "trueFalse";

          content.appendChild(selectList);

          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = "true";
          option.text = "true";

          selectList.appendChild(option);

          var option2 = document.createElement("option");
          option2.value = "false";
          option2.text = "false";

          selectList.appendChild(option2)
        }

        if (jsonCol.visible === true && jsonCol.type === "String" && jsonCol.dropdownList === null) {

          var content = document.getElementById("formcontent");

          var inputTitle = document.createElement("header");
          inputTitle.textContent = jsonCol.name;


          content.appendChild(inputTitle);

          var formInput = document.createElement("input");
          formInput.type = "text";
          formInput.placeholder = jsonCol.name;
          formInput.name = "text";

          content.appendChild(formInput);

        }

        if (jsonCol.visible === true && jsonCol.type === "String" && jsonCol.dropdownList != null) {

          var content = document.getElementById("formcontent");

          var listTitle = document.createElement("header");
          listTitle.textContent = jsonCol.name;

          content.appendChild(listTitle);

          var selectListLong = document.createElement("select");
          selectListLong.name ="longList";

          indiceList++;

          content.appendChild(selectListLong);


          for (const options of jsonCol.dropdownList) {

            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = options;
            option.text = options;

            selectListLong.appendChild(option);

          }
        }
      }
      var submit = document.createElement("input");
      submit.type = "submit";
      content.appendChild(submit);
    }
  }
```

It's then conditionnally called in my HTML window with a simple `<div id="formcontent"> </div>`

I tried using document.getElementByName('...').value, doesn't seem to work.

Btw, if you have another idea on how to make that form, I'd like hearing it as well, this method seems a bit messy I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = document.getElementById("formcontent").value;
```

You can try it by ID

Comment: Using getElementById("formcontent").value gives me error "Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'". I tried with nodeValue, doesn't change anything. What I did is I completed the form, hit submit, and then pressed a button that called this function: 
`retrieveForm(){
    var content = document.getElementById("formcontent").value;
    console.log("contenu", content);
  }`
All I get is content is null... am I doing this right?